# Change the shadow color of the textfield when got focus

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want my textfield to get blue color shadow when the user taps on the textfield to enter text. I would like to get an example that would update the inputCls inside focus event.
I have set the inpuCls while creating the textfield. I wanted to how know to add it inside FOCUS event.
can anyone help me on this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `listener` in your `TextField` that listens to the [event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-event-focus) `focus`.

The listener can then change the [inputCls](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-cfg-inputCls) to what you want.

If you want, you can then listen to the `blur` event to revert the changes with the same logic.

I strongly suggest you read the documentation about events :

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/guide/events

EDIT : Code sample

```
listeners : {
    focus: function() {
        yourTextfield.setInputCls('yourcls');
    }
}
```

Comment: Saffron, I know this. My question wasn't clear sorry for that. Let me edit my question

Comment: Once again, looking at the documentation gives you the setInputCls() method of TextField to change the inputCls dynamically, just put it in your listener's function. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-method-setInputCls